# Set hint of EditText in TextInputLayout to multiline?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Is it possible to set hint of EditText in TextInputLayout to multiline?
Here's my layout.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/f1q3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/f1q2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/f1q3_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint= "@string/hint1"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And here's my string resource for hint.

```
 <string name="hint1">
    A quick brown fox jumps \n over the lazy dog
</string>
```

Comment: Try to add <br /> instead of \n in xml file or use this sentence programmatically in java file it may be use

Comment: See this thread it might help u
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455169/7022347)