# Multiline does not work inside TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline, textinputlayout

Whatever I do, I couldn’t manage to make my `EditText` multilined inside `TextInputLayout` (had to add `InputLayout` for character counter).
So when I enter something, it goes horizontally instead of going to a new line after a while.
As you know very well, inside normal `EditText`s, multiline does the trick but not in this case. What do you think? Thank you.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adViewNewEntry"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.134">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:padding="28dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="280"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/save_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top|left"

                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="10"


                android:scrollbars="vertical"

                />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="256dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="saveToDatabase"
        android:text="SAVE"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adViewNewEntry"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adViewNewEntry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 17):

This works too:

```xml
android:inputType="textPersonName | textMultiLine"
```

Comment: This should be documented on the material Text field page. This is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 12):

I did it. You have to add 'programatically' `edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);` for your related EditText.

The interesting thing in my case is when you add multiline code to xml multiline does not work(with TextInputLayout) but it works this way. Hope it s helpful for some of us.

Comment: Saved my day! It's a pity the xml options don't work, when it's their job to do so...

Comment: Good to hear it helped you friend. still it's a mystery why it works only that way though

Comment: As of today, it should be working now if define in XML layout. `android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"`

Comment: Correct, and as of today, just

android:inputType="textMultiLine"

works!!